# Is there anyway in RealityKit to Ignore Tap Events on a Particular Entity?

Tags: swift, realitykit

I have the following code:

```
let floor = ModelEntity(mesh: floorMesh, 
                   materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, isMetallic: true)])
floor.name = "floor"
floor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
floor.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, 
                                               material: .default, 
                                                   mode: .static)
```

And I want to ignore tap events on the floor entity. Is this possible? Currently I use the "floor" name and ignore it inside the handleTap event.